# How to detect or prevent wild pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dangling-pointer

This very simple code demonstrates the kind of trouble wild pointer causes in a complex environment.

```
int main()
{
    int *a1 = new int;
    int *tmp = a1;
    delete a1;
    // Now, the tmp pointer is a wild pointer, it's dangerous.

    int *a2 = new int;
    delete tmp;
    // Now, the a2 pointer may be a wild pointer.
}
```

Is there any way to detect or prevent the problem? Do smart pointers help here?

Comment: ¤ "such as smart pointer..." yes that's a correct answer. why did you ask?

Comment: Your second `delete` will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach actually,I want to ask any other way except smart pointer becouse I'm now help some projects detect the wild problem,so less code modify is better

Comment: @mark - use leak detection tools and `new`/`delete` overrides to debug deleted areas. These are known techniques, you should ask the right questions. What you asked doesn't relate to what you actually need, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Use smart pointers. Why not?

The code you have is invalid and will lead to undefined behavior, but regardless - C++ is not very strict when it comes to memory usage, that's the beauty of it (and the curse...). There are external tools that help detecting leaks (although not a case like you've shown), but it basically comes down to using the right constructs and programming correctly. C++ allows a lot of flexibility, but if not used right - you get nasty bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use (at least on Linux) tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to chase such bugs.

And you could also use [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) (and not bother about releasing memory).

Some (IMHO badly designed) classes require to be deleted (i.e. because they do important things in destructors, in addition of releasing memory) or should not have manual pointers to instances.

Read more about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (which is very common in C++, but is not an universal mantra: good Ocaml code don't follow it, for instance).

And you could use smart pointers.

Comment: "because they do important things in destructors" Yes, that's a part of RAII.

Comment: ahahahahahaha... Badly designed classes like most of the C++ standard library.

Comment: @Mankarse: They might not be top-notch but they're still leagues ahead of what you find in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is very simple:

> Always be clear about the ownership of resources in code, and enforce this ownership through the use of classes which manage the lifetimes of the resources.

In this case, (assuming that you need to use pointers at all), the lifetimes that I would suggest are as follows:

```
//Limit the scope of the variables to the minimum required:
{
    //a1 owns the pointer, so make it a `unique_ptr`
    std::unique_ptr<int> a1(new int);
    //tmp does not own the pointer, so make it a raw pointer
    //limit its scope to a shorter scope than a1
    int *tmp = a1.get();
}
//now the tmp pointer does not exist. It cannot be dangerous

//A similar strategy applies here
{
    //a2 owns the pointer
    std::unique_ptr<int> a2(new int);
}
//Again, a2 goes out of scope before any damage can occur.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int *a2 = new int;
delete tmp;
//now, the a2 pointer may be a wild pointer
```

No, the pointer `a2` points to a valid (not free'd) location.

As far as I know, there is no such way to find out if a pointer points to a valid (not free'd) place in memory per se.

For your first example, you could use a `std::shared_ptr` to model this shared ownership over the allocated memory location.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to unit test your code as much as possible, run your program and unit tests using tools like valgrind, and hope to catch all memory access problems.

Answer (score 0):

With C, nobody prevents you from shooting yourself into the foot.

There are ways to make yourself the life easier, such as C++ smart pointers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_Smart_Pointers

Tools such as valgrind will override the `delete` statement, and mark memory as invalidated, so that subsequent access can be detected and reported. For example it is popular to overwrite such supposed-to-be-deleted memory with values such as `0xDEADBEEF` that stick out when debugging, so you know quickly that you are accessing a deleted memory area.

For production, you usually want to skip writing to no longer needed memory, so these things should only be enabled in debugging mode.